# i am getting this error well please helpme out i have used spring 4.0.1 jars in my project

Tags: spring

Dec 15, 2016 7:01:00 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6d21714c: startup date [Thu Dec 15 07:01:00 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 15, 2016 7:01:00 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'humpty': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private beans.Dumpty beans.Humpty.dumpty; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [beans.Dumpty] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: dumpty2,dumpty1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at test.Humpty_Dumpty_Autowiring_Test.main(Humpty_Dumpty_Autowiring_Test.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private beans.Dumpty beans.Humpty.dumpty; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [beans.Dumpty] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: dumpty2,dumpty1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [beans.Dumpty] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: dumpty2,dumpty1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 15 more
C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

> Could not autowire field: private beans.Dumpty beans.Humpty.dumpty;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [beans.Dumpty] is defined: **expected single
>   matching bean but found 2: dumpty2,dumpty1**

I guess in your application context, you defined two beans named dumpty1 and dumpty2 of the same type beans.Dumpty. Therefore, when injecting the bean, you should make use of the @Qualifier with the name of the bean (`e.g. @Qualifier("dumpty1")`) to let spring know which bean to get.